# Add and Remove Custom attribute in fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw grid on canvas with custom attribute. After that trying to remove that grid using those added custom attribute.

So Grid is showing on canvas, but when i am trying to remove the grid. it's not working.

## Code

```
//Draw Grid
function draw_grid(){
    var grid = 50;
    canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(o) {
        if(o.custom_class == 'canvas_grid') {
            console.log(o.custom_class);
            canvas.remove(o);
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
        var grid_line1 = new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {
            stroke: '#ccc',
            selectable: false,
            'custom_class' : 'canvas_grid'
        });
        canvas.add(grid_line1);

        var grid_line2 = new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {
          stroke: '#ccc',
          selectable: false,
          'custom_class' : 'canvas_grid'
        });
        canvas.add(grid_line2);
    }
}

draw_grid();

/* Hide/Show Grid */
$(document).on('change','#show_grid',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
       draw_grid(); 
    }
    else
    {
        canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(o) {
            if(o.custom_class === 'canvas_grid') {
                canvas.remove(o);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

## Codepen

https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/OQEzVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the [visible](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#visible) property, no need to add and remove all time.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
//Draw Grid
function draw_grid() {
  var grid = 50;
  var lines = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= 600; i += grid) {
    lines.push(new fabric.Line([i, 0, i, 300],{stroke:'#000',strokeWidth: 2}));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= 300; i += grid) {
    lines.push(new fabric.Line([0, i, 600, i],{stroke:'#000',strokeWidth: 2}));
  }
  gridObj = new fabric.Group(lines, {
    selectable:false,
    evented:false,
    hoverCursor: 'auto',
    left: -2,
    top: -2,
    visible:false
  });
  canvas.add(gridObj);
  canvas.renderAll();
  console.log(gridObj.toJSON())
}

draw_grid();

/* Hide/Show Grid */
$(document).on('change', '#show_grid', function() {
  gridObj.visible = $(this).is(':checked');
  gridObj.dirty = true;
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Show Grid: <input type="checkbox" id="show_grid" /> 
<canvas id="canvas1" width="600" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/wyYmEz).

Or

Get all the objects having `custom_class = canvas_grid` property and remove them using `canvas.remove()`. Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/oEadrY).

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to pass that grid on server side, so if visible is off then it will include in .toJSON or not?

Comment: Just for knowledge perspective, is there a way to fix it using the way i have done?

Comment: @DS9 it will include

Comment: @DS9 check [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/oEadrY), get all the lines and remove using `canvas.remove()`

Comment: thanks a lot. so basically you have added custom class in array and after that removed that from object, right? What is the meaning of canvas.remove(...objs), i mean ... (triple dot)

Comment: @DS9 its [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: thanks, please also include that codepen, so that's the answer my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165828/discussion-between-ds9-and-durga).